# Need current syntax for writing an FQL query in PHP

Tags: facebook-fql, facebook-comments

Because using the Graph to get comment information craps out at a certain volume (even with pagination) I need an FQL solution.  Unfortunately, all the documentation and blogs I've found contain deprecated samples making it impossible for me to figure out the correct syntax.

I need to understand how to get this:

```
SELECT object_id, post_id, fromid, time, text, username 
FROM comment 
WHERE object_id 
  IN (SELECT comments_fbid FROM link_stat WHERE url='*** EVENT HREF ***')
```

into a PHP variable so I can access the data from a decoded JSON object like so:

```
$fql_obj = json_decode($fql_query, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out.  For anyone else confused by it you append it to a graph lookup and replace spaces with +s:

```
$fql_query = "https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT+object_id,+post_id,+fromid,+time,+text,+username+FROM+comment+WHERE+object_id+IN+SELECT+comments_fbid+FROM+link_stat+WHERE+url='***EVENTHREF***')";

$fql_obj = json_decode($fql_query, true);
```